# Returning keyerror on calling function

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm having an issue with testing this BeautifulSoup crawler. Forgive me if there is some obvious mistake, since this is my third hour into Python. I have this code below...

```
def huffpost_crawl():
 article_list = []
 DOMAIN = 'huffingtonpost.com'
 huff_soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("http://www.huffingtonpost.com").read())
 news_list = huff_soup.find_all("div", {"class", "snp_most_popular_entry"})[0]
 for news in news_list[0]:
    title = news('div', {'class', 'snp_most_popular_entry_desc'})[0].a.get_text()
    full_url = news('div', {'class', 'snp_most_popular_entry_image'}).a["href"]
    blurb = ""
    thumb_url = news('div', {'class', 
   'snp_most_popular_entry_image'}).a.img["longdesc"]


 print title

huffpost_crawl()
```

When I run `pythong test.py` in my terminal, I'm returned with...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 21, in <module>
  huffpost_crawl()
File "test.py", line 11, in huffpost_crawl
  for news in news_list[0]:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 879, in __getitem__
  return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
news_list = huff_soup.find_all("div", {"class", "snp_most_popular_entry"})[0]
for news in news_list[0]:
```

Just remove one of those two `[0]` bits and the problem (or at least this problem—I can't guarantee that the rest of your code does what you want) will go away.

I won't explain why the code was wrong, because you really need to learn to debug your code and figure this stuff out yourself.

Start by doing this in an interactive interpreter:

```
>>> huff_soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("http://www.huffingtonpost.com").read())
>>> news_list = huff_soup.find_all("div", {"class", "snp_most_popular_entry"})
```

See what that returns—what shape is it, and how do you get to the part you want interactively? Once you know that, it should be obvious how to do it in your script.

Even in cases where things are too complex to play with interactively, you can log stuff with print statements, run in the debugger, etc. Don't just blindly stare at code that doesn't work and say "Why doesn't it work?", or post the code somewhere and ask someone else why it doesn't work, or you'll never learn anything.

Comment: Well this is my 3rd hour into using python.

Comment: @jason328: I think you're doing things backward, and it will hurt you in the long run. Try playing with things interactively, and then think about how to turn them into robust scripts; don't try to write robust scripts first and then later learn to debug. In the old days, people had to submit programs on hand-punched cards and wait 3 hours to see if they worked, but we don't have to do that anymore.

Comment: I agree. I'm just in a situation where I don't have time to play with things. I didn't even have python installed in my computer three hours ago.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `news_list` is a dictionary (key-value pairs) and doesn't have a key of `0`. That would have worked if it was a list you were trying to index. Therefore, instead of your

`for news in news_list[0]:`

line, try

`for key, news in news_list.iteritems():`

This will iterate through each of the items in the dictionary. If you just want the first result, I'm not sure how you'd determine that. Try printing out the items to determine what is returned.

Comment: I'm being returned with `TypeError: NoneType object is not callable`

Comment: Them perhaps your `find_all` isn't finding anything? Try printing `news_list`.

Comment: I'm now being returned with `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable` again

Comment: On which line? Don't want to get into a big off topic debugging discussion, so see which line the error is thrown on, and go backwards from there. I suspect your find_all line isn't finding anything.

Comment: As it turns out, this is wrong. But it was clearly just a guess, and not a bad one.